# Dockerfile run /bin/bash id ENTRYPOINT or CMD fails

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to run /bin/bash in the case that the CMD or ENTRYPOINT programs fails.

So: `CMD top && /bin/bash`

I want that when I close top with cntrl-C I get a shell in the container.

Thank you

Comment: You are using && which means "if the first command succeeds, run the second command". This is not what you want. Just separate commands with a semi-colon, so no matter why the first command exits, the second one starts

Comment: I've alredy tried that and it does not work. :( It keeps kicking you out of the container

Comment: Maybe try something like `bash -c 'top; bash'`

Comment: that worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it:

`CMD bash -c 'top; bash'`